# What HA DR options allow the secondary server to be queryable?

Tags: sql-server

I want to implement solution such that the secondary server database is queryable.

Amongst the following options:

1. Log shipping
2. Transactional replication
3. Database mirroring
4. Always on failover clustering
5. Always on availability groups

Which of the above methods allows the secondary server database to be online and queryable?

Are there any more options other than the above 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log shipping

- Secondary Database is "normally" in a recovering state so that additional backups can be applied
- Secondary database can be made readable between restores by restoring with STANDBY
- Users on secondary must be disconnected so that the next restore can take place

Transactional replication

- Primary and Secondary databases are independent and can have transactions on bot sides
- Secondary database is not restricted to READ-ONLY. Users can make updates if they have permissions
- Be wary of updates on the Secondary that could cause issues with future replication updates from the Primary
- Secondary is always online

Database mirroring

- Deprecated technology
- Requires a Database Snapshot to be taken to allow a queryable copy
- Snapshot Database will have a different name from the Primary and Secondary
- No updates applied to Snapshot
- Snapshot will increase in size as changes made to Secondary because of copy-on-write process
- Need to drop the snapshot (disconnecting users) and recreate it to get newer data

Always on failover clustering

- There is only 1 copy of the database in Failover Clustering - it is the ownership of the storage that changes on a failover.  This has no Secondary to make available for querying

Always on availability groups

- Allows a Secondary to be set to read-only
- Continuously updated from Primary

Be wary also of license restrictions if you make secondary copies queryable.